# Python Discord Bot isn't joinig voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I'm logged in as {0.user}.".format(client))
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("!test"):
        await message.channel.send("Test passed successfully!")
@commands.command()
async def join(self,ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")
    voice_channel = client.get_channel(ctx.author.voice.channel.id)
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
        await ctx.send("idk")
@commands.command()
async def disconnect(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```

The bot doesn't join I don't know what I did wrong. It should only join my voice channel nothing else. I watched [this](https://youtu.be/jHZlvRr9KxM) Tutorial but as I said it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing metaphors a little:  your `on_message` is a plain function:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("!test"):
        await message.channel.send("Test passed successfully!")
```

Whereas your `join` and `disconnect` functions look as if they belong in a class (note the `self` argument):

```
@commands.command()
async def join(self,ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")
    voice_channel = client.get_channel(ctx.author.voice.channel.id)
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
        await ctx.send("idk")
@commands.command()
async def disconnect(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```

If you remove the `self` argument from those functions, you should be able to get it working:

```
async def join(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")
    voice_channel = client.get_channel(ctx.author.voice.channel.id)
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
        await ctx.send("idk")
@commands.command()
async def disconnect(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```